# Theorem 6.13 from Walter Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis

Tags: measure-theory

(Rudin, Real and Complex Analisys, chapter Complex Measure, page 125 in 3rd edition)

**Theorem 6.13:**
Suppose $\mu$ is a positive measure , $g \in L^1(\mu)$,and
$\lambda(E)=\int_{E} g d\mu$. Then
$$|\lambda|(E)=\int_{E} |g| d\mu$$
*Proof.*
By Theorem 6.12, there is a function $h$, of absolute value 1, such that $d\lambda=hd|\lambda|$. By hypothesis, $d\lambda=g d\mu$. Hence $hd|\lambda|=g d\mu$. This gives $d|\lambda|=\bar{h}g d\mu$.

I don't understand the last sentence:
Since $| \lambda | \geq 0$ and $\mu \geq 0$, it follows that $\bar{h}g \geq 0$ a.e. [$\mu$], so that $\bar{h}g=|g|$ a.e. [$\mu$]

Why  $\bar{h}g=|g|$ ?

I am very thankful for the help.

PS. $|\lambda|$ means variation of measure $\lambda$.

Comment: Not all of us have the book on-hand, can you reproduce the full statement?

Comment: Yes, I did it now.

Comment: $\lvert h\rvert \equiv 1$, so we have $\overline{h(x)} g(x) = \lvert g(x)\rvert \iff \overline{h(x)} g(x) \geqslant 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Above if and only if works only when $|h|=1$?

Comment: Depends on how you quantify. For a given $g$, it may also work in other cases. E.g. if $g \equiv 0$, the equivalence holds (trivially) for all $h$. But if it shall hold for all $g$, then you need $\lvert h\rvert \equiv 1$. (Note that the direction $\implies$ always holds, it's the other direction that may fail, at points where $g(x) \neq 0$ and $\lvert h(x)\rvert \neq 1$.)